# Exception in Google Apps Script with Library

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a script in my spreadsheet

```js
function runMe(){
  var app = UiApp.createApplication()

  var hidden=app.createHidden('info','info')
  app.add(hidden)  

  var buttonOk = app.createButton('Ok');
  var handler = app.createServerClickHandler('selOk');
  handler.addCallbackElement(hidden);
  buttonOk.addClickHandler(handler);
  app.add(buttonOk)

  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(app,'title')
}

function selOk(e){
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('ok')
}
```

it is working fine but when I include any library the script rise "Error encountered..." when I push Ok button

Comment: Well.. it looks like the library has a problem. Can you share its id/code?

Comment: it is known Issue https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=3982&q=Type%3DDefect%20library&colspec=Stars%20Opened%20ID%20Type%20Status%20Summary%20Component%20Owner